# How do you calculate combined orders of growth?

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory, space-complexity

Suppose I have a recursive procedure  with a formal parameter *p*. This procedure

1. wraps the recursive call in a ***Θ(1)*** (deferred) operation
2. and executes a ***Θ(g(k))*** operation before that call.

*k* is dependent upon the value of *p*. [1]

The procedure calls itself with the argument *p/b* where *b* is a constant (assume it terminates at some point in the range between *1* and *0*).

**Question 1**. 
If *n* is the value of the argument to *p* in the initial call to the procedure, what are the orders of growth of the space and the number of steps executed, in terms of *n*, for the process this procedure generates

- if ***k = p***? [2]
- if ***k = f(p)***? [3]

---

#### Footnotes

[1] i.e., upon the value of the argument passed into *p*. 
[2] i.e., the size of the input to the nested operation is same as that for our procedure. 
[3] i.e., the size of the input to the nested operation is some function of the input size of our procedure.

---

#### Sample procedure

```scm
(define (* a b)
  (cond ((= b 0) 0)
        ((even? b) (double (* a (halve b))))
        (else (+ a (* a (- b 1))))))
```

This procedure performs integer multiplication as repeated additions based on the rules

- **a * b = double (a * (b / 2))** if *b* is even
- **a * b = a + (a * (b - 1))** if *b* is odd
- **a * b = 0** if *b* is zero

**Pseudo-code:**

```
define *(a, b) as
{
    if (b is 0) return 0
    if (b is even) return double of *(a, halve (b))
    else return a + *(a, b - 1)
}
```

Here

- the formal parameter is *b*.
- argument to the recursive call is *b/2*.
- `double x` is a ***Θ(1)*** operation like `return x + x`.
- `halve k` is ***Θ(g(k))*** with ***k = b*** i.e., it is ***Θ(g(b))***.

**Question 2**.
What will be the orders of growth, in terms of *n*, when `*(a, n)` is evaluated?

---

#### Before You Answer

Please note that the primary questions are the two parts of **question 1**.

**Question 2** can be answered as the first part. For the second part, you can assume *f(p)* to be any function you like: *log p*, *p/2*, p^2 etc.

Comment: Why is `double n = Θ(1)` when `halve n = Θ(g(n))`? (Assuming `a, b` are of arbitrary precision)

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Because a division operation is not directly available. `halve n` must compute `n / 2` and this is not necessarily `Θ(1)`.

Comment: My point is that big-O analysis is only relevant if `a, b` are of arbitrary precision, i.e. `double n` should not be a `Θ(1)` operation.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Ok I get your point. But for our purposes, assume as Asaf said that `+` and `-` are primitive `Θ(1)` operations. We want to abstract these so we can focus on our higher-level analysis.

Comment: In any case, the procedure given is only representative. My question is primarily about the general case. Also, I have mentioned `Θ` (theta) and not `O` (big-O) in the question (in case they differ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw someone has already answered question 2, so I'll answer question 1 only.

First thing is to notice is that the two parts of the question are equivalent. In the first question, **k=p** so we execute a **Θ(g(p))** operation for some function **g**. In the second one, **k=f(p)** and we execute a **Θ(g(f(p))) = Θ((g∘f)(p))**. replace **g** from the first question by **g∘f** and the second question is solved.

Thus, let's consider the first case only, i.e. **k=p**. Denote the time complexity of the recursive procedure by **T(n)** and we have that:
**T(n) = T(n/b) + g(n)** [The free term should be multiplied by a constant **c**, but we can talk about complexity in "amount of **c**'s" and the theta bound will obviously remain the same]

The solution of the recursive formula is **T(n) = g(n) + g(n/b) + ... + g(n/b^i) + ... + g(1)**
We cannot further simplify it unless given additional information about **g**. For example, if **g** is a polynomial, **g(n) = n^k**, we get that
**T(n) = n^k * (1 + b^-k + b^-2k + b^-4k + ... + b^-log(n)*k) <= n^k * (1 + b^-1 + b^-2 + ....) <= n^k * c**  for a constant **c**, thus **T(n) =  Θ(n^k)**.

But, if **g(n) = log_b(n)**, [from now on I ommit the base of the log] we get that **T(n) = log(n) + log(n/b) + ... + log(n/(b^log_b(n))) = log(n^log(n) * 1/b^(1 + 2 + ... log(n))) = log(n)^2 -  log(n)^2 / 2 - log(n) / 2 =  Θ(log(n) ^ 2) =  Θ(g(n)^2).**

You can easily prove, using a similar proof to the one where **g** is a polynomial that when **g = Ω(n)**, i.e., at least linear, then the complexity is **g(n)**. But when **g** is sublinear the complexity may be well bigger than **g(n)**, as **g(n/b)** may be much bigger then **g(n) / b**.

Comment: Nice answer! I'd like to discuss a few points though: 1) I noticed that you have ignored the `Θ(1)` deferred operation. I feel that the recurrence relation should have been **T(n) = T(n/b) + g(n) + 1** i.e., if the recursion happens _x_ times, that should add an _x_ term to the overall complexity (_x_ being _log\_b n_ here). 2) In your polynomial example, why the switch to **<=**? Wouldn't it be just as correct to say **T(n) = n^k \* (1 + b^-k + ...) = n^k \* c**, implying **T(n) = Θ(n^k)**? I think it matters because `Θ` is a tight bound and using **<=** only gives an upper bound.

Comment: Regarding the second question, the upper bound was to prove that indeed it's a constant (by a geometric series). the lower bound is obvious, **T(n) >= n^k** and we get the theta bound. Regarding the first question, you are right. that means **T(n) = Omega(log(n))** as the function is called **log(n)** times. so when **g(n) = o(log(n))** then **T(n) = Θ(log(n))**, otherwise the original analysis holds

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the wort case analysis.

First, 
you can approximate the solution by using powers of two:

If [image: b=2^n] then clearly the algorithm takes: [image: \Theta(n* g(k))] (where [image: n=log b]).

If it is an odd number then after applying -1 you get an even number and you divide by 2, you can repeat this only [image: log b] times, and the number of steps is also [image: \Theta(log b * g(k))], the case of b being an odd number is clearly the worst case and this gives you the answer.

(I think you need an additional base case for: b=1)

Comment: Also, I am primarily looking for the answer to the first question (which has two parts). Sorry if this wasn't clear, I've edited my question to make this explicit.

Comment: The first question is a kind of confusing, What do you means with f(n)? It seems that you can solve this question applying the Master theorem:

Comment: Thank you. I've clarified my question to differentiate between _n_ (which is the initial value) and _p_ (_b_ in the given example) which is the formal parameter to which _n_ is passed. I wanted to mean _f(p)_. Please see the added footnotes. You can assume it to be any function of _p_ you like.

Comment: **Note:** this answers **question 2** for the case where **k = n** i.e., where `halve` is **Θ(g(n))**. In the question though, it is **Θ(g(b))** i.e., the cost of calling it changes with every successive recursion call.

Comment: Also, the variable names denote different things from those in the question, possibly causing confusion. To be fair though, at the time you answered it, the question text said _'the recursion happens T(b) = log b times.'_ where it should have been in terms of _n_. I apologize for that.